# node.js post request a new post and python check if there is new post posted

Tags: python, node.js, post, request

ive been wondering how I can detect if there is a new post posted in python.

i want to create a new post with node js and then with python i wanna send a message to my discord server if there is a new post made.

how do I do this?

can I detect new post requests in python?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, what have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: i have no code, because I dont have any solution how to do this. And I dont want code...